# intellij auto completes a tag without href

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2016

I know that when doing

`a` `TAB` it used to auto complete to `<a href=""></a>` this is no longer the case for me. It simply does this: `<a></a>` Is there a way to turn this back on? in html and php files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create create Live Template from `Preferences > Editor > Live Templates` to associate `a TAB` with `<a href=""></a>`.

Here's an example:

[image]

In this example the text `<a href=""></a>` has been associated with Abbreviation: a and has been configured to Expand with Tab.